# Binding & connecting using sockets in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, sockets

Here is an issue with a socket I am having:

```
Public Sub Connect(ByVal server As String, ByVal port As Integer)
        Dim IP As IPAddress = IPAddress.Parse(server)
        Dim EP As IPEndPoint = New IPEndPoint(IP, port)
        sock.Bind(EP)
        sock.Connect(server, port)
    End Sub
```

The socket is declared like this, at the top of the code:

```
Dim sock As Socket
```

What is wrong here? It says Object reference not set to an instance of an object, which is a NullReferenceException.

Thanks for your help! This is in vb.net by the way, and I have imported the proper namespaces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does the code ever assign a new instance of Socket to the Sock variable? sounds like the object is null because no assignment has been made to the variable.

**EDIT**
Initializing the socket could be done like this:

```
 sock = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Udp)
```

Assuming that you are using IPV4 and that you want to read and write bytes from the socket like a stream. As for the protocol... I've specified UDP here but that will depend on what you are trying to talk to.

Comment: K, what is the proper syntax? I didn't know what AddressFamily or SocketType or ProtocolType to specify.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim MonSocketClient As New Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp)
```